# React Native functional components - Navigate between different screens, each on a separate .js file

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

In my **functional-component**-based React Native app, I want to navigate between different screens, each of which resides in a separate `.js` file. I want to be able to navigate multiple layers deep like this:

[`Screen1.js`] <-> [`Screen2.js`] <-> [`Screen3.js`] <-> [`Screen4.js`]

For some reason, [the examples](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=Hello%20React%20Navigation%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40expo%2Fvector-icons%40*%2C%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40*%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%40*%2Creact-native-pager-view%40*%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E4.7.2%2Creact-native-reanimated%40*%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40*%2Creact-native-screens%40*%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E3.0.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%406.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%406.1.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Felements%401.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%406.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%406.0.2%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative-stack%406.0.5%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%406.0.2%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%406.0.6&hideQueryParams=true&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F6.x%2Fpop-to-top.js) in [the tutorial](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating) place all the screens within the same `App.js` file, each as their own separate function, which I would imagine is unusual developer behavior.

I would prefer to have the navigation stack in a single `NavigationService.js` file, which is then imported by each `Screen#.js` file. How could I implement this? (I've seen several SO answers on this, along with some online tutorials, but seemingly most of them implement **class** components instead of **functional**.)

Below is my attempt at implementing this environment, but when I try to navigate to a new screen, I get `_NavigationService.default.navigate is not a function. (In '_NavigationService.default.navigate('Email')', '_NavigationService.default.navigate' is undefined)`.

**NavigationService.js:**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import EmailScreen from './Email';
import HomeScreen from './App';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
  
function NavigationService( navigation ) {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Camera" component={CameraScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Email" component={EmailScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default {navigation, NavigationService};
```

**App.js (HomeScreen):**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import NavigationService from './NavigationService';

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
    <Button buttonStyle={styles.cameraButton} titleStyle={styles.buttonText}
    onPress={() => NavigationService.navigate('Email')}
    title="Email pics"
    />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  cameraButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 24
  }
});

export default HomeScreen;
```

**Email.js (EmailScreen):**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import RNSmtpMailer from 'react-native-smtp-mailer';

function EmailScreen() {

    return(
        <View>
            <Text>Test hi hi hi</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
export default EmailScreen;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to import your `NavigationService` in your individual screens. React Navigation takes care of that and injects a `navigation` property that you can use instead.

Use e.g.

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
    <Button buttonStyle={styles.cameraButton} titleStyle={styles.buttonText}
    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Email')}
    title="Email pics"
    />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Your `NavigationService` would only be used somewhere in your entrypoint to render the stack navigator, and I suggest to rename it to avoid the misconception that it could be passed around as a service. It's simply a component in your app's hierarchy which establishes the navigation stack, and React Navigation ensures that the stack screens get the necessary properties like `navigation` or `route` (e.g. to fetch navigation parameters from).

For that reason, you also don't have to pass a `navigation` property into your `NavigationService`.

[Here](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-native-navigation) is a great tutorial with functional components distributed over multiple files.

Comment: It's a confusing new concept to me that `({navigation})` can magically be called within a different `.js` file without importing `NavigationService.js` first. Thank you. I did not know that was possible. A Discord user recommend I pass `HomeScreen(props)` as a parameter instead, and do `props.navigation.navigate('Email')`. They both work. And yes, a tab with that tutorial you linked was pulled up for 6 of the 8 hours of my workday. It was too convoluted for my simple brain to parse & implement the essential information in my project. (It was also a frustrating idea that I even had to do so)

Comment: React Navigation injects this property into your screen, and it's not the same as your `NavigationService`. --- Both ways of extracting properties are the same, `({ navigation })` is just a bit easier to write. You'll also find mixtures like `({ prop1, prop2, ...remainingProps })` often used when your component needs `prop1` and `prop2` and the rest is simply passed down.

Comment: Something within my `NavigationService.js` is injecting the `navigation` prop into my entire app, I assume. Whether that's `const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()`, `import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';`, `import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';`, or `export default NavigationService`. *One* of those things has got to be the trigger for the global availability of `{navigation}` among all my project's `.js` files, yes?

Comment: Not all your `.js` files, just the screens you declare like so: `<Stack.Screen name="Email" component={EmailScreen} />` - keep in mind that your `EmailScreen` isn't rendered right away here. The component is simply passed as a property and React Navigation decides when and how to render it. And when it does, it simply adds its own `navigation` object as a property which provides all the fancy navigation functionality: `return <YourComponent navigation={reactNavigationsNavigationObject} />;` - and you can now use it. (NB: Obviously this is over-simplified.)

Comment: Oh cool. That makes sense! Simple explanations are good for me :) Thank you for being a positive example for SO